# How to request a GET to Ipstack API from a RESTFul service in Java

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, ip-geolocation

I'm trying to get location of the user by the IP using the API IPStack. This method is overloaded with the original. The idea was if the User receives the location goes to the other function and if not to this one with the lookup and get it. Maybe I should use JQuery or PHP uCurl how the examples of the documentation of https://ipstack.com/documentation, but I didn't nothing how to do it from Eclipse with Java (It's a must) so I still trying it like a RESTful service but nothing.

```
public Users newUser(String username, String email) {
    Client cliente = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget servicio = cliente.target(MONGODB + MONGOCOLL + "?apiKey=" + MONGOKEY);

    try {
        JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject location = new JSONObject();
        user.put("username", username);
        user.put("email", email);

        ArrayList<String> following = new ArrayList<String>();
        user.put("following", following);
        ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();
        user.put("friends", friends);

        String ipstackfields = "&output=json&fields=country_name,city,zip";
        Client clientipstack = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget ipstackserv = clientipstack
                .target(IPSTACK + IPSTACKEND + "?apiKey=" + IPSTACKKEY + ipstackfields);
        Response resplocated = ipstackserv.request().get();
        String slocate = resplocated.readEntity(String.class);
        JSONObject located = new JSONObject(slocate);

        location.put("country", located.get("country_name"));
        location.put("city", located.get("city"));
        location.put("postcode", located.get("zip"));
        user.put("location", location);

        Response respuesta = servicio.request().post(Entity.json(user.toString()));

        if (respuesta.getStatus() == Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
            // TODO: leer la respuesta de la llamada y trasformar el objeto
            // JSON a un mensaje para devolverlo
            String s = respuesta.readEntity(String.class);
            JSONObject usuario = new JSONObject(s);
            return JSONtoUser(usuario);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems executed on the server side. When your method `newUser` is invoked, you need to retrieve the client IP from the request header and pass it to the Geolocation API.

The request header to look for depends on your server and configuration but is usually called `Client-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For`.

Once you have the client IP, you need to append it before query parameters with Ipstack.

FYI, I recommend looking at [Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co) for a faster and more reliable solution than Ipstack (disclaimer: I run the service). Here is how to pass your information with Ipregistry:

https://api.ipregistry.co/54.85.132.205?key=tryout

where `54.85.132.205` and `tryout` must be replaced respectively by your client IP and your API key.